# Warning: iso c99 requires whitespace after the macro name

Tags: iphone, ios7

I want to define the large string means multiline text in macro. But is giving error.
I tried this

```
#define kTerms&Conditions(message) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ready to get:\"%@\".Find out how here.", message];
```

Above is demo text, actual is very lengthy. But that is giving the warning also.
My text is like

```
@"USER TERMS AND CONDITIONS

PLEASE READ THIS BEFORE ACCESSING THE SERVICE.  BY ACCESSING THE , YOU AGREE TO
BE BOUND BY THE TERMS AND CONDITIONS BELOW.  IF YOU DO NOT WISH TO BE BOUND BY 
THESE TERMS AND CONDITIONS, YOU MAY NOT USE THE SITE.

1. ALL PERSONS USING THIS  SITE AGREE TO REPORT (MANIFESTS) IN ACCORDANCE WITH
   49 U.S.C. SECTION 4909(C), 19  PART 122, 8 U.S.C. SECTION 1, AND 8 C.F.R.
   PARTS 217, 231, AND 251.

2. ELIGIBILITY FOR USE OF AND ACCESS TO THIS MCL/APIS SITE IS SUBJECT TO FINAL
   APPROVAL AND ACCEPTANCE BY UNIVERSAL.
```

Above is the text I want to show in Macro. 
Non-ASCII characters are not allowed, giving error.
Please guide.

Comment: You can only use Alphanumeric for macros, so sayeth the AppleDocs https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/tags/tags.html. Also you are defining a runtime function on a compile time macro. You cannot do this.

Answer (score 1):

`kTerms&Conditions` is *not* a valid macro name, it's actually *two* identifiers, separated by the `&` token. The reason you're getting the error is because the compiler assumes you want:

```
#define kTerms &Conditions ...
```

but you haven't got the required separator between the macro name and definition.

I suggest you use `kTermsAndConditions`.

---

In more depth, `C99 section 6.4.2` places specific restrictions on what has to be deemed an identifier. It's basically alphabetic characters, digits and the underscore, with the proviso that it cannot start with a digit.

It's actually a *little* more complex than this since the standard allows for UCNs (mostly alphabetic characters from an array of other languages) and "other implementation-defined characters" but you'll be safe if you stick to the  guidelines in the previous paragraph.

Comment: Ya thats right thanks but the text mentioned above still doesn't fit i it.

Comment: Non-Ascii characters are not allowed, giving error.

Comment: @iPhone6, I have no idea what you're talking about there. I get the exact same error as you in a "normal" C99 compiler when using `kTerms&Conditions` which is fixed when you change it to `kTermsAndConditions`. Hence _that's_ the answer to this particular problem. If you get _another_ problem once you've fixed that, it should be a separate question, with more detail as to what is happening. SO is not meant to be a bulletin board or problem solving site where we gradually fix _all_ your problems in a single question, it's a Q&A site - one Q, one A :-)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question or have not gone through it properly. I mentioned the text in the question that i want to set in macro, and also mention the problem facing in it. You just told the mistake not the solution of the problem.

Comment: The solution is to get the ampersand out of your macro name - kTerms&Conditions should be kTermsAndConditions. The compiler is complaining about the '&' - it may not be part of the macro name, hence the compiler thinks the macro already ended, hence it says there should be a space between the macro name and the & ...

Comment: @iPhone6, your question title is `iso c99 requires whitespace after the macro name`. That's caused by the `&` in the macro name and the _solution_ is to not use `&` - if there is a _different_ problem, you need to elucidate on that, there's nowhere near enough info for us to do anything other than guess. Step 1, change the macro name to remove `&` and see if problem disappears.

Comment: in may case, the offending char was a `-`. Never would have guessed this. Thanks!